# Scroll issue with RecyclerView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I have a RecyclerView where each item is a linear layout (orientation vertical) with a text view and another horizontal RecyclerView. The expected behaviour would be that the user would be able to seamless change from vertical to horizontal scroll, but it appears if user tries to swipe horizontally while the vertical scroll is not entirely stopped (yet not visible move, just to swipe fast) or if the horizontal swipe starts somehow from a diagonal motion, the app keeps the vertical scroll and ignores the horizontal one.
Is there a best practice on how to use a vertical recyclerview with horizontal recyclerview items? Tried to search for this a lot, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: are you looking for this https://bladecoder.medium.com/fixing-recyclerview-nested-scrolling-in-opposite-direction-f587be5c1a04

Comment: yes, I giving it a try, thanks!

Comment: even with that workaround, the behavior is not perfect. I saw something like this working perfectly in flutter, still wondering how to achieve that in android

Comment: the person who posted that blog also has created a issue on issuetracker. hope its resolved by google

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168716647?pli=1 link to the issue as well for easier reach in the future